# Get value of td if it's a hyperlink in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to color the column that matches.. it was working untill now but if i make one of the column as link. My code doesnot work. Reallya appreciate the help

```
<table id="T1" border='1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Middle Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Suffix</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>78</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="T2" border='1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Middle Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Suffix</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-modal">34</a></td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bat</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-modal">man</a></td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>21212</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>james</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-modal">bond</a></td>
      <td>007</td>
      <td>dadadada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-modal">34</a></td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>78</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br /><br /><br /><br />

<button id="btn">color if matches</button>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamsrk/fojz5e56/21/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fojz5e56/23/)**

Instead of `.html()` function you should use `.text()` :

```
if((firstname.text() == firstname1.text())&&(middlename.text() == middlename1.text()) && 
(lastname.text() == lastname1.text())&&(suffix.text() == suffix1.text())) {
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you added a link to that last row

```
  <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-modal">34</a></td>
```

is not the same as

```
  <td>34</td>
```

use `.text()` instead of `.html()`

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fojz5e56/26/

Answer (score 1):

Check for `.text()` content instead of `.html()` content.

`.html()` returns html content as

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#new-modal">34</a>
```

while `.text()` returns just the text as `34`.

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kr5jrboa/1/